# Creating a simple calculated field in Access

Tags: ms-access, macros

I have three fields F1,F2 & F3. The first two fields are filled with numbers. How can I automatically set the value for the third field "F3 = F1 - F2" like in Excel? Perhaps it can be done with macros?

Comment: This is a very basic question http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/add-a-text-box-control-to-a-form-or-report-HA010075983.aspx

Comment: Unless the OP means [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/add-a-calculated-field-to-a-table-HA101820564.aspx), which in any case is a [bad idea](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider whether `F3` must be an actual field in your table.  Its value is derived from a simple computation, so you can perform that computation with a query field expression whenever you need it.

```
SELECT F1, F2, (F1 - F2) AS F3
FROM YourTable;
```

If you have a compelling reason why `F3` must be a real field, you can execute an `UPDATE` statement to store the values.

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET F3 = F1 - F2;
```

The first approach is generally preferred because it ensures the computed `F3` values will always be consistent with the current `F1` and `F2` values.  If you don't store `F3`, you needn't change stored `F3` values in response to changes in `F1` and/or `F2` values.

Comment: thanks, after OO.org Base Access is so flexible and powerful